# mongodb - Fields vs children performance

Tags: mongodb, database-performance

In mongodb, if read & write performance is the goal rather then memory or etc, is it better to store data in documents with many fields, or is it better to store data in fewer fields generally with some of the fields referencing child objects?

Or in other words, does storing data in child objects have performance costs vs storing that data in multiple fields and vice versa.

e.g.

```
document = {
    'field1' : 1,
    'field2' : 2,
    'field3' : {
         'childfield1' : val1,
         'childfield2' : val2,
         ...
         'childfieldn' : valn // where n could be reasonably large
    }
}
```

vs

```
document = {
    'field1' : 1,
    'field2' : 2,
    'childfield1' : val1,
    'childfield2' : val2,
    ...
    'childfieldn' : valn
}
```

Hope that was clear, apologies if it wasn't.

Comment: I would expect performance to be the same.  But run a test for your specific situation to verify.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to embed information in one document, but this document should be less than 16MB. Other way you will need to make extra requests to retrieve referenced items.